# Infinite families

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to try and understand infinite families of sets better. What are some examples of

**(1) an infinite family of open sets whose intersection is not open**

**(2) an infinite family of closed sets whose union is not closed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may consider $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology.

1. We have $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n\geq1}\left]-\frac1n,\frac1n
       \right[=\left\{0\right\}$
2. We have $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n\geq1}\left[0,1-\frac1n
           \right]=\left[0,1\right[$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the natural numbers $\Bbb N$ and let $n$ denote a natural number.  Let $a \in \Bbb R$ be a fixed real number.

For (1): $\{ (a - \frac{1}{n}, a + \frac{1}{n}) \}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a countably infinite family of open intervals.  Their intersection is not open.  Why?  What is $\bigcap \limits_{n =1}^{\infty} (a - \frac{1}{n}, a + \frac{1}{n})$?

For (2): $\{ [ 0 + \frac{1}{n + 4}, 1 - \frac{1}{n + 4}] \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a countably infinite family of closed intervals whose union is not closed.  Why? What is $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} [ 0 + \frac{1}{n + 4}, 1 - \frac{1}{n + 4}]$?